# Integral Representation for the Square of the Airy Fuction

Tags: airy-functions

Formula 9.11.3 in DLMF states that$$\text{Ai}(x)^2=\frac{1}{4 \pi 
   \sqrt{3}} \int_0^{\infty }
   J_0\left(\frac{t^3}{12}+x
   t\right) t \, dt$$
where $J_0 $ is the Bessel function of the first kind of order zero. I am looking for a derivation of this result. Perhaps one can obtain this result from a related formula $$\text{Ai}(x)^2=\frac{1}{2 \pi
   ^{3/2}} \int_0^{\infty }
   \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}} \cos
   \left(\frac{t^3}{12}+x
   t+\frac{\pi }{4}\right) \,
   dt$$